# Verify hashed passwords from MySQL database using Prepared Statements

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, password-hash

I'm trying to verify my user's hashed password from my MySQL Database using the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions. I am trying to do this with prepared PHP statements for added security but with having no luck. Anyone know why?

Here's the code:

```
//check if password is linked to username
$checkpass = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_password FROM user_details WHERE user_password=?");
$checkpass->bind_param("s", $preppass);
$preppass = $password;
$getpass = $checkpass->execute();

//get and check result
$checkpass->bind_result($getpass);
$checkpass->fetch();
if (!password_verify($password, $getpass)) {
    echo "<script>console.log('Incorrect username or password!')</script>";
    return false;
    exit;
}
echo "S<script>console.log('Successfully logged in!')</script>";
$conn->close();
```

and here is the database:

[Database Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7bNL.png)

What I've tried:

[Unable to extract password hash from database with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049076/unable-to-extract-password-hash-from-database-with-prepared-statements)

[Verify hashed password from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842118/verify-hashed-password-from-database)

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Many thanks!

Comment: what is the output you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look up the hashed password using the username, not the password, because you don't know what the hashed password is. Then you use `password_verify()` to check that the entered password matches the hashed password.

```
$checkpass = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_password FROM user_details WHERE username=?");
$checkpass->bind_param("s", $username);
$checkpass->execute();

//get and check result
$checkpass->bind_result($getpass);
$checkpass->fetch();
if (!password_verify($password, $getpass)) {
    echo "<script>console.log('Incorrect username or password!')</script>";
    return false;
    exit;
}
echo "S<script>console.log('Successfully logged in!')</script>";
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your prepared SQL statement is using `?` (`WHERE user_password=?"`), it looks like `$checkpass->bind_param("s", $preppass);` is trying to bind `$prepass` to parameter `:s` that does not exist.

Either use `WHERE user_password=:s"` (declare a named statement parameter), or `$checkpass->bind_param(1, $preppass);` (bind your plain password to the first `?` in the statement).

[As per the documentation.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).